# How to execute 'Premain' method not getting invoked with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jar, exec-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.test.MainClass</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-javaagent:target/final-jar.jar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The final-jar.jar has a manifest file with 'premain'; however, it is not never executed. Can someone help here?

Comment: No error as such, a sysout in premain method never got control and the line was never printed on the console. From this I inferred that the premain method is not getting executed. However, I was able to make it work. I'll go ahead and answer the question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me finally. I changed the  tag to  tag. And it worked.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.test.MainClass</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>-javaagent:target/final-jar.jar</commandlineArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works with the maven goal 'java' of the 'exec-maven-plugin'.